# How to generate a non-periodic square signal in scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, convolution

I would like to translate the following simple square from 0 to 1 function in a scipy.signal in order to use the convolution operation with an other scipy.signal

```
def f(t): return 1 if (np.floor(t) < 1) else 0
```

How can I do that?

## Edit

Sorry for the confusion, assuming that I have the following function definition :
`return np.where(np.floor(t) < 1, 1 , 0)`

How can I write a scipy.signal version of it ?

Comment: `[f(x) for x in np.linspace(0, 3, 100)]` will give a list that can be used with scipy.  Operating element by element isn't the best practice with numy, the answer by @Tonechas shows a better way to do it with numpy.  Also, you'll want `np.abs(t) < 1` for a rect function.  As it stands right now you've created a step function.

Answer (score 0):

NumPy's [`where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) might be what you are looking for:

```
def f(t):
    return np.where(np.floor(t) < 1, 1 , 0)
```

Comment: What would be this function in scipy.signal type? (sorry for the confusion)

Comment: There is no such function in `scipy.signal` - at least for a non-periodic square wave that you're seeking.  You have to make your own.  For a periodic square signal (i.e. with a known duty cycle), try `scipy.signal.square`: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.square.html#scipy.signal.square